# Deploy word addin ... 2003

Tags: deployment, ms-office, add-in, office-2003, word-2003

I created a word addin for office 2003 with VS2008. It works fine but i can't deploy it.
I created 2 virtual machine (XP mode): One dev, one "client". On dev, the solution is deployed but i have no idea how (when i run VS maybe ...) and on the client i followed this : 
[How to: Prepare End User Computers to Run Office Solutions (2003 System)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2ac08ee2%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) but it doesn't work. I can't find another "step-by-step tutorial" to compare with this one.
all suggestions are welcome ...

---

edit : Here are the steps i follow :

1. Office 2003 is completely installed
2. Update to Office SP3
3. Installation of .NET 2.0
4. Installation of .NET 3.5 SP1
5. Installation of Office 2003 PIA
6. Installation of Visual Studio Tools for Office Runtime
7. Installation of my Word Addin via the setup project (Release mode)
8. Granting fulltrust : Caspol.exe -m -ag 1 -url "C:\Office*" FullTrust -n "My_Policy"

I verified the register too but all seems to be fine (i tried to change the name "MyAddin" with the Guid we can find in the .csproj file but nothing changed)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK i found a solution to add it on a machine which has only Office 2003 installed : Install following

1. .NET Framework 2.0
2. .NET Framework 3.5 SP1
3. Office 2003 PIA
4. Visual Studio 2005 Tools for Office SE Runtime
5. Visual Studio Tools for the Office system 3.0 Runtime
6. Visual Studio 2005 Tools for Office Second Edition Sample
7. Install your addin via the setup project

You need to grant FullTrust to your addin, to do so you can type this :

```
%WINDIR%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Caspol.exe -q -m -ag 1 -url "\*" FullTrust -n YourAddin.dll
```

Then verify that this Registry Keys are here with the good values : [Registry Entries for Application-Level Add-ins](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386106%28v=vs.90%29.aspx).

In my case, the LoadBehavior value were set to 3 but when i run word for the 1st time, it is change to 2. Set it back to 3 and it should work.